# How to override base constructor arguments

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

If I make a python class which overrides another class, does `__init__` get called from base class? What if I want to specify arguments for it?

Base class:

```
class bar(object):
    def __init__(self, somearg = False):
        # ...
```

New class

```
class foo(bar):
    def __init__(self)
       # ???
```

What do I want?

```
obj = foo() # somearg = True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the base class `__init__` method is not called, since your derived class provides a new version of the method.

You'd call the parent `__init__` method explicitly through the `super()` proxy and pass in the argument to set a different default:

```
class foo(bar):
    def __init__(self)
        super().__init__(somearg=True)
```